# dynamically generating json from json for highcharts heap map chart using ajax

Tags: highcharts

i have data in my datatable (c#), i plan to send the data to the JS so that highcharts heatmap can understand and plot the heatmap.

### following is the structure of datatable (c#)

```
xaxis yaxis value color
0       0    50   green
0       1    60   yellow
1       0    66   red
1       1    60   yellow
```

i want json in the below format so that highchart can understand

```
[
{x:0,y:0,value:50,color:'green'},
{x:0,y:1,value:60,color:'yelow'},
{x:1,y:0,value:66,color:'red'},
{x:1,y:1,value:50,color:'green'}
]
```

please help me in getting the desired output.once i get the desired output i will set to the chart using

```
chart.series[0].setdata(jsondata);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it going from the "datatable" to the json format?

Comment: if i try to set the data as in the line chart.series[0].setData(JSON.parse( [ [0,0,50], [0,1,10] ])); then highcharts is able to plot the heatmap chart,but if i try to set the data as in the line chart.series[0].setData(JSON.parse([{x:0,y:0,value:50},{x:0,y:1,value:10}])); then i am getting error "invalid character" and pointing error at the statement.

looks like there is a problem with highcharts api.
any help is highly appreciated
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left out code and error handling but I think this is sort of what you are looking for.

```
/// <summary>
/// serializable class that represent one data point
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
class heatmap
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use a public static function to copy data from the data table 
    /// to the list object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<heatmap> createHeatMap(ref DataTable table)
    {
        List<heatmap> list = new List<heatmap>();
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            heatmap map = new heatmap();
            map.x = Convert.ToInt32(row["x"]);
            map.y = Convert.ToInt32(row["y"]);
            map.value = Convert.ToInt32(row["value"]);
            map.color = Convert.ToString(row["color"]);
            list.Add(map);

        }

        return list;
    }

}

// your code that populates the datatable
//blah blah blah

List<heatmap> map = heatmap.createHeatMap(ref datatable);
// I use newtonsoft for serialization
string jsonMap = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map);
return jsonMap;
```